# Replace printf with cout statements

Tags: shell, c++11, awk, sed

I'm trying to write a script which could inline replace a printf statement with the cout statement. It could be either in sed or awk.

For example, if printf statement is

```
printf("int=%d, str=%s", i, s) ;
```

Then it should be replaced with :

```
cout << "int=" << i << ", str=" << s;
```

printf statement could have any no. of arguments. Accordingly, cout statement should be generated and replaced inline.

Other such examples could be:

```
printf("Statement2: %d %d %s %f", i, j, s ,f);
printf("statement3: %d %f",
        i,
        f);


CString failedMsg;
failedMsg.Format(_T("FAILED Triggered=%d expected=%d in %s"),
                            (int)i,
                            (int)j,
                            static_cast<LPCTSTR>(__TFUNCTION__));
```

Output:

```
cout << "Statement2: " << i << " " << j << " " << s << " " << f;
cout << "statement3: " << i << " " << f;

    std::stringstream failedMsg;
    failedMsg << "FAILED Triggered=" << (int)i
        << " expected=" << (int)i
        << " in " << __TFUNCTION__;
```

Yes, I'm new to StackOverflow. I'll learn the way how it works and how to ask for help. But for right now I'll just request for your gracious support to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: `I tried many way but none of them work as expected.` do add your attempts to the question...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.

Comment: You have forgotten the comma and the space; try with `std::cout << "int=" << i << ", str=" << s;`; try also adding a `std::flush` at the end to force the flush

Comment: if `sed 's/.*printf.*/cout << "int=" << i << "str=" << s;/' file` isn't all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements including what variations of `printf` you need to replace (with examples) if it's not just that one.

Comment: What do you do with `%8.3f`? Emit the `ostream` manipulators required to do the same thing?

Comment: I will delete my answer and if I could find the correct one then put it

Answer (score 0):

───▄██▄─██▄───▄
─▄██████████▄███▄
─▌████████████▌
▐▐█░█▌░▀████▀░░
░▐▄▐▄░░░▐▄▐▄░░░░

> using **Perl** if your `printf` function is on a single line not separate line; otherwise I think you cannot

for something like:

```
printf("int=%d, str=%s", i, s) ;

    std::cout << "one" << '\n'; // just for sure

printf("one=%d, two=%d, three=%d, four=%d, five=%d", a, b   , c, d   ,   e);

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ){
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
```

you can:

```
perl -ne '$T=0;/printf/ && s/printf|[ ",;()]+|%[a-z]/ /g && (@A=split) && ($T=1);if($T){$s=($#A+1)/2;$n=0;print "std::cout << ";print "\"$A[$n] \" << $A[$n+++$s] << " for 1..$s;print q("\n":),"\n";}else{print}' file
```

the output:

```
std::cout << "int= " << i << "str= " << s << "\n":

    std::cout << "one" << '\n'; // just for sure

std::cout << "one= " << a << "two= " << b << "three= " << c << "four= " << d << "five= " << e << "\n":

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ){
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
```

---

For something like:

```
printf("Statement2: %d %d %s %f", i, j, s ,f);

std::cout << "one" << '\n'; // just for sure

printf("Statement2: %d %d %s %f", i, j, s ,f);

        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ){
             std::cout << i << '\n';
        }
```

You can use: ( as script.sh )

```
perl -ne '$T=0;/printf/ && s/printf|[ ",;()]+|%[a-z]/ /g && (@A=split) && ($T=1);if($T){$n=0;print "std::cout << \"$A[0] \" << ";print " $A[++$n] <<" for 1..$#A-1;print q( "\n"),"\n"; }else{print}' file
```

the output:

```
std::cout << "Statement2: " <<  i << j << s << "\n"

std::cout << "one" << '\n'; // just for sure

std::cout << "Statement2: " <<  i << j << s << "\n"

        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ){
             std::cout << i << '\n';
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @k-five. It really worked well, even if it's not in sed and awk. I could use it for most of replacements. But there is one more scenario where it failed.I updated that scenario also with 'failedMsg'. So I request you to help me there.

Comment: @DeepSingh Do you mean: `printf("int=%d, str=%s", i, s) ;` this one

Comment: @DeepSingh It is so much complex. Also I just solve this one: `printf("Statement2: %d %d %s %f", i, j, s ,f);` and not this one: `printf("int=%d, str=%s", i, s) ;` **In such case you need more than one script for each part**